# delphi customclass deepcloning by referencing and dereferencing pointers

Tags: delphi, pointers, cloning

Hi I want to deep clone a custom class that contains other subclasses which is too many to support by assign() way.

To simplify, I createinstance with RTTI and use my switch procedure

to clone OriginalInlineContent : TInlineContent;

```
NewInstance := TInlineContent.CreateInstance(OriginalInlineContent, ...)//with RTTI and instance is good to go this returns TInlineContent
```

Now i wanna switch the reference of the OriginalInlineContent and NewInstance

```
class procedure TInlineContent.SwitchMemory(Source, Destination:
    TInlineContent);
var P, S : ^TInlineContent;
    SourceSize, DestinationSize : integer;
begin
  Assert(Source <> nil);
  Assert(Destination <> nil);

  SourceSize := SizeOf(Source);
  DestinationSize := SizeOf(Destination);

  P := @Source;
  S := @Destination;
  Destination := @P;   **//possibly replace destination with P means @S is scrambled?**
  Source := @S;

  Assert(SizeOf(Source) = DestinationSize);
  Assert(SizeOf(Destination) = SourceSize);
end;
```

And it seems to work for source but not destination. How do I achieve this?

Comment: If the intent, as implied by the words rather than the code, is to create a new instance with a copy of the data from an existing instance then this needs to be somewhat more complicated.  If you copy the memory content (which isn't what your code actually does) then you will have issues that you have simply copied references for all reference types but haven't followed any management requirements.  Any sub-objects will be references to the existing sub-objects of the reference instance rather than new copies, any managed types will be missing use count increments.

Comment: This sort of thing could be done by browsing the RTTI in detail but that would be a much more elaborate bit of code.  You could consider using the API in REST.Json to convert your object to JSON and back - ObjectToJsonObject followed by JsonToObject<TInlineContent> but this would be extremely expensive in processor time.  If efficiency is not important then this could work for you but it does still have some annoying undocumented limitations.

Comment: Hej Kanitatlan, thanks for the answers. U are right on both accounts. The expensive REST solution is not ideal. I'm guess RTTI extensive copying field to field, property to property,...etc might help but complicated. I will find another solution to get me out of this bind.

Comment: If you have the Delphi source code then the REST Json library can be used to give you an example of iterating through the RTTI to copy an object but ultimately your only efficient option (if that matters) is to implement an "assign".